# Single page application in JavaScript isn't autoloading when file saved in Nginx

Tags: javascript, html, nginx, debugging, single-page-application

I have the following minimalist code, when I run it on VSCode live server, and then I change anything like changing the title :

```
Vanilla SPA Router
```

to :

```
Vanilla SPA
```

in the editor, as soon as I save it, it will auto update the page, and I don't have to refresh the page to see the new content.

However, when I used Nginx server, I have to refresh the page manually. How can I make it auto reload content in Nginx?

I have also set those options in the nginx.conf file :

```
 server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {
          if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
          }
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }   

    }
```

```js
const urlPageTitle = "JS Single Page Application Router";

// create document click that watches the nav links only
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const { target } = e;
    if (!target.matches("nav a")) {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    urlRoute();
});



// create an object that maps the url to the template, title, and description
const urlRoutes = {
    404: {
        template: "/templates/404.html",
        title: "404 | " + urlPageTitle,
        description: "Page not found",
    },
    "/": {
        template: "/templates/index.html",
        title: "Home | " + urlPageTitle,
        description: "This is the home page",
    },
    "/about": {
        template: "/templates/about.html",
        title: "About Us | " + urlPageTitle,
        description: "This is the about page",
    },
    "/contact": {
        template: "/templates/contact.html",
        title: "Contact Us | " + urlPageTitle,
        description: "This is the contact page",
    },
};

// create a function that watches the url and calls the urlLocationHandler
const urlRoute = (event) => {
    event = event || window.event; // get window.event if event argument not provided
    event.preventDefault();
    // window.history.pushState(state, unused, target link);
    window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);
    urlLocationHandler();
};

// create a function that handles the url location
const urlLocationHandler = async () => {
    const location = window.location.pathname; // get the url path
    // if the path length is 0, set it to primary page route
    if (location.length == 0) {
        location = "/";
    }
    // get the route object from the urlRoutes object
    const route = urlRoutes[location] || urlRoutes["404"];
    // get the html from the template
    const html = await fetch(route.template).then((response) => response.text());
    // set the content of the content div to the html
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html;
    // set the title of the document to the title of the route
    document.title = route.title;
    // set the description of the document to the description of the route
    document
        .querySelector('meta[name="description"]')
        .setAttribute("content", route.description);
};

// add an event listener to the window that watches for url changes
window.onpopstate = urlLocationHandler;
// call the urlLocationHandler function to handle the initial url
window.route = urlRoute;
// call the urlLocationHandler function to handle the initial url
urlLocationHandler();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
        <title>Vanilla SPA Router</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.5.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="output">
            <nav id="main-nav" class="sidebar">
                <a href="/" onclick="route()">Home</a>
                <a href="/about" onclick="route()">About</a>
                <a href="/lorem" onclick="route()">Lorem</a>
            </nav>
            <div id="main-page"></div>
        </div>



  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The VSCode live refreshing likely works via Websockets. It sets up a Websocket connection on connect, and then when you save in your IDE, it pushes a message to the frontend to get it to restart. You may need to set that up in Nginx.